# CSV template output without knowning whats in the CSV

Tags: python, django

I have a CSV which I load...

```
import csv
file = upload.filepath
file_read = csv.reader(file)
data = [row for row in file_read]
```

In my template I want to list each item without having to know the name....

I think what I need is to count how many items are in the row, loop that amount of times getting each item? maybe?

So my output could be

```
myemail,mynumber,test@test.com,1
myemail2,mynumber2,test@test2.com,2
```

Or even

```
myname,0897654543
myname,0897654w543
```

either way I never know how many columns are in the csv

**Update:**

So could I just do this?

```
{% for item in data %}
   {% for i in item %}
    {{ i }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The data in the rows have no name. They are lists, not dictionaries. What kinds of columns does your CSV contain?

Comment: it can contain different columns each time, the CSV will have no set format. thats my issue I cannot just say get my all user.values because there may not be a user.

Comment: All your rows are just lists with strings: `[['myname', '0897654543'], ['myname', '0897654w543']]` for your second example.

Comment: I see, yes it is, updated question, is that santx correct?

Comment: Why don't you try that out?

Comment: yep that seems to work thanks @Martijn Pieters In the old days that was called a nested loop and always bad code tho? Is this the way to do it in Python?

Comment: You can join the lists into strings beforehand if that is how you want to display them in your template; but you are using a nested structure here (lists in lists) so nested loops is *one* way to process those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "In my template I want to list each item".  But if you just want to print out each row, you can do

```
for row in file_read :
    print row
```

or to print each item individually,

```
for row in file_read :
    for item in row :
        print item
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)?

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt("yourfile.csv",delimiter=",")
```

This will make `data` a numpy array with as many columns as are in your csv file..